# Adding a border to picture(plot) in a PPTX generated by python and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, powerpoint

[image]I have a plot which is generated by matplotlib then I save it as .png and then I place it on a PPT file using the pptx module. 
I want to add the border of the pic in my PPT file can any one please help me for the code..??

```
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('dashboard.pptx')
left = Inches(0.5)
top = Inches(1)
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_masters[0].slide_layouts[2])
pic = slide.shapes.add_picture('test.png',left, top,width =None ,height =None)
prs.save('dashboard_new.pptx')
```

Comment: Does the current solution crop the boarder of `test.png`? What should it look like and what does it currently look like in powerpoint? It seems to me that it would be easier to change the image in matplotlib before adding to the presentation

Comment: Just Added the pic Smith.. have a look at it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Picture` object in python-pptx has a `line` attribute that provides access to border properties:

- http://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/shapes.html#picture-objects
- http://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/dml.html#pptx.dml.line.LineFormat

So the code would go something like this:

```
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

line = pic.line
line.color.rgb = RGBColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00)
line.width = Inches(0.1)
```

Comment: Hi Scanny it works but with a slight modification. Instead of            line.color = RGBColor(128,128,128)     we need to use                              line.color.rgb = RGBColor(128,128,128)

Comment: Ah, yes, of course, I remember that now that you mention it :)  I've updated the code example to reflect.

Answer (score -1):

Shapes (in this case your pic object) have a .Line property that controls the border around the shape.  Here's an example of how you'd add the line in VBA. In your case, you'd modify the same .Line properties of your pic object:

```
Sub AddBorder()

    Dim oSh As Shape

    ' this assumes that the current shape is selected
    ' in other cases, you'd work with an object reference
    ' generated when you added the shape
    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

    With oSh
        ' if you don't set the line to be visible,
        ' you get odd results
        .Line.Visible = msoTrue
        .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Line.Weight = 6    ' in points
    End With

End Sub
```