# python pptx how to add border for a chart?

Tags: python, python-pptx

Install

```sh
pip install python-pptx==0.6.18
```

Code

```py
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData

prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])
shapes = slide.shapes
shapes.title.text = ' '

chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data)
prs.save('test.pptx')
```

Actual

[image]

Expect

[image]

I want to add border for this whole chart, but I can't find any API from [python-pptx Documentation](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/cht-series.html).

How to solve it?

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421858/adding-a-border-to-pictureplot-in-a-pptx-generated-by-python-and-matplotlib answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

```py
from pptx.util import Inches
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE
from pptx.chart.data import CategoryChartData

prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[5])
shapes = slide.shapes
shapes.title.text = ' '

chart_data = CategoryChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['East', 'West', 'Midwest']
chart_data.add_series('Series 1', (19.2, 21.4, 16.7))
x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(6), Inches(4.5)
graphic_frame = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data)
chart = graphic_frame.chart

from lxml import etree

xml = '<c:spPr><a:ln><a:solidFill><a:schemeClr val="tx1"/></a:solidFill></a:ln></c:spPr>'
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
element = etree.fromstring(xml, parser)
chart._chartSpace.append(element)

prs.save('test.pptx')
```

[image]

Comment: do you know of a way to remove the rounded corners as well?

Answer (score 2):

```
xml = '<c:roundedCorners val="0"/>'
parser = etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
element = etree.fromstring(xml, parser)
chart._chartSpace.append(element)
```

Use this code to remove rounded corners.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).